# Check if Visitor paid a specific amount + if he used a specific "code" to access a special website/download

Tags: php, paypal, confirmation

currently I'm working on my own, selfwritten Website (from scratch, without any CMS or sh**) and I want to implement a special system for the Commissions I make.
Some people are commissioning me to create 3D Models and other stuff.
Since sometimes my customers are from a different timezone (I'm from germany, most of my customers are from america) communicating over Discord sometimes fails because of that.

So I thought about creating a system to let the customers download their commissioned model as soon as I've uploaded it and sent them a Code to "unlock" the download to it.

I thought this probably could work using Paypal. They get the Code, enters them on my website and gets the information to pay a specific amount I've setup before. After they paid, the download is unlocked.

Any Idea how I could setup something like that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd use Laravel for creating something like this; but you need to write the code :)

Comment: Ofc I want to write the code for this by myself :D Just need some headups how to start with this :)

Comment: I am not quite sure which part you are asking about. You need to create a simple token when payment goes through and let them download the file via the code.